# `Ffmpeg` aptitude install seems to break packages.

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, aptitude

I tried to install `ffmpeg` because I thought/think it is needed for compiling OpenCV. However, when trying to do that I think I screwed up. How can I undo what I did?

```
$ sudo aptitude install ffmpeg
The following packages will be REMOVED:  
libalut-dev{u} libalut0{u} libcoin60{u} libgeos-3.2.2{u} libgeos-c1{u} libhal1{u}
    libhdf4-0-alt{u} libnetcdf6{u} libogdi3.2{u} libopenal-dev{u} libproj0{u} 
    libxerces-c28{u} proj-bin{u} proj-data{u} unixodbc{u} 
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 15 to remove and 16 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 25.1 MB will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] y
(Reading database ... 222527 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libalut-dev ...
Removing libalut0 ...
Removing libcoin60 ...
Removing libgeos-c1 ...
Removing libgeos-3.2.2 ...
Removing libhal1 ...
Removing libhdf4-0-alt ...
Removing libnetcdf6 ...
Removing libogdi3.2 ...
Removing libopenal-dev ...
Removing proj-bin ...
Removing libproj0 ...
Removing libxerces-c28 ...
Removing proj-data ...
Removing unixodbc ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place

Current status: 43955 new [+14349].
$ sudo aptitude safe-upgrade 
Resolving dependencies...                
Unable to resolve dependencies for the upgrade: no solution found.
Unable to safely resolve dependencies, try running with --full-resolver.
```

Please comment if more information are needed.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. For others:

I did `aptitude why ffmpeg` and it gave `k9copy` and `dvdrip`. I removed those. Then I removed `ffmpeg`. That might not have been the problem. `apt-get dist-upgrade -s` gave me a list ob packages that were to be upgraded. The first one being `libboost-all-dev`. Again, `why` told me that it was not needed, so I `remove`d it. Only three packages were left now. All being in combination to libboost- Those were packages I had installed by hand before the upgrade. I removed those and now the system is clean again.